# Two columns working with same data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have problem with my SQL query.

I have two tables - the first one has ID and ID of persons:

```
id | id_p | id_p2
1  |   1  |  2
2  |   2  |  3
...
```

In the second one, I have ID of Persons and their names

```
id_p | name
1    | John
2    | Alice
3    | Daniel
...
```

What I need - I need to get one SQL query, which will return back to me name of persons, but every id_p in a different column. So I need id_p with names and id_p2 with names too. Example here

```
id | id_p | id_p2 | name_p | name_p2
1  |   1  |   2   |  John  |  Alice
2  |   2  |   3   |  Alice |  Daniel
...
```

How can I do this? Many thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Can u put sample output in the question?

Comment: @Prathibha - Added output in the question.

Comment: @YogeshSharma - tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `SELF JOIN` :

```
select t.id, p.name as FirstIdPerson, p2.name as SecondIdPerson
from table t inner join
     person p
     on p.id_p = t.id_p inner join 
     person p2
     on p2.id_p = t.id_p2;
```

Comment: @Martin Kadlcek you need to add `t.id_p,t.id_p2` to the select statement above.